# What is the difference: "go" vs "will go"

Tags: future-tense

I was doing an exercise and came across this:

> My friends ... a leaving party before they ... abroad.(have, go)

So what would be the correct one and why:

> My friends **will have** a leaving party before they **go** abroad.
>
> My friends **will have** a leaving party before they **will go** abroad.

Seems that the first one is more natural, but could you please give some explanation?

Comment: Usually, a good-bye or farewell party. ****Before**** never takes will. The usual tenses that can follow it are; present, simple past, pluperfect or present perfect. Like when.

Comment: I feel like this question actually comes up a lot here, but I'm not sure how to search for it.

Comment: @Lambie - I think it's a not quite correct to say "before never takes will".  "I bet I'll get home *before you will!*" sounds natural enough to me, although I'd rather say "before you do".

Comment: "Before" is like "if", "when", "after" in this respect: none of them normally admit "will": hence "My friends will have a party *before/after/when/if* they go abroad".  However, there are exceptions.  If by "before" we were expressing preference rather than chronology, we could use "will": "He'll make a deal with the devil before he'll go abroad" could mean roughly "he'd sooner make a deal with the devil than go abroad".

Comment: I bet I'll get home before you do.

Answer (score 1):

An attempt at a short answer: *will (verb)* means that the action of *verb*-ing is in the future, basically.

We want to say "X will happen before Y" where Y is some action in the future; "go abroad" in this case.  But right now, they already *will Y*, because the going abroad is in the future.  Therefore it doesn't make sense to say that something will happen *before they will Y*, because they already "will Y".